# sysctl migrate to 2.6.35

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel, sysctl

I have userspace sysctl calls made to sysctl tables configured on a 2.6.24 kernel.  I have migrated the sysctl code to 2.6.35 kernel. I'm seeing warning msgs sayg that 'deprecated sysctl warning' when i make sysctl() calls from userspace. The same is workinng on 2.6.24. Does anyone have any idea on this. Also, sysctl handler do_sysctl islocated in sysctl.c in 2.6.24 whereas in 2.6.35 is located in sysctl_binary.c oa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sysctl()` system call has long been considered deprecated; indeed the man page has said this for some time:

> Or rather... don't call it: use of this system call has long been
>   discouraged, and it is so unloved that it is likely to disappear in  a
>   future kernel version.  Remove it from your programs now; use the
>   `/proc/sys` interface instead.

As it says, you should rewrite your userspace portion of the code to use the `/proc/sys` interface.

Comment: you should rewrite your userspace portion of the code to use the /proc/sys interface. -- Can you explain me more on this? Any example or online resource would be helpful.